# Push objects into array in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

```
  List returnMovies = [];

Future<List> _getData() async {

    final response = await http.get("https:../getTodayMovies",
        headers: {HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: Acess_Token.access_token});


    if (response.body != null) {
    returnMovies = json.decode(response.body);
      .....

      setState(() {});
    } else {
       final responseUpcoming = await http.get("/upcoming",
        headers: {HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: Acess_Token.access_token});
        returnMovies = json.decode(responseUpcoming.body);


    }
```

The response.body looks like:

```
[{"id":394470548,"host_group_name":"heyab redda","movie_image":"..png","type":"horror","code":"X123","name":"Lovely","start_time":1554364800,"end_time":1554393600,"}]
```

The responseUpcoming.body looks like:

```
 {"id":394470545,"host_group_name":"foo redda","movie_image":".png","type":"horror","code":"X123","name":"Lovely","start_time":1554364800,"end_time":1554393600,"}, {"id":394470548,"host_group_name":"foo1 redda","movie_image":"..png","type":"comic","code":"X125","name":"Lovely1","start_time":1554364800,"end_time":1554393600,"}
```

The error I get is: String, dynamic is not a subtype of type `List<dynamic>`.

In the first API call that I am doing I normally get in return an array of objects, however, when this is empty, the second API call returns a list of objects that I want to push into the array called returnMovies, how can I achieve this?? Is there any way to .push these objects in the array?? So then I want to use this array to build dynamically a Listview.builder.
Also is it correct the way I am declaring it? I am quite new on Dart. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `addAll`

```
returnMovies.addAll(json.decode(returnUpcoming.body))
```

Comment: Yes I actually do, however, I get error: <String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>.

Comment: You can't add a `Map` (key-value pairs) to an `Iterable` (list of values). You would need to provide more details what you want to accomplish (how the data in `returnMovies` and `returnUpcoming.body` looks like exactly and what the resulting `returnMovies` should look like)

Comment: I just edited my post, with the potential response of my API call and how I would like to use its data, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I will suggest to use

```
returnMovies.addAll({your object here})
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this `json.decode(response.body)` you are getting a `List` of `Map` you should use `List<dynamic> movieListData` and get the items like this:

```
    movieListData = json.decode(response.body);
    returnMovies = movieListData.map((dynamic movieData) {
          String id = movieData['_id'];
          String host_group_name = movieData['host_group_name'];
          String duration = movieData['duration'];
          return new Movie(id,title, duration);
        }).toList();
```